# Cannot find valid codec for transcoding video with VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, ffdshow

I'm not 100% sure I am even asking the right question here, but basically I want to wrap a 4k webcam in a transport stream using VLC so that I can use it as an IPTV server or sorts in some additional software.

What I have so far:

```
vlc dshow:// :dshow-vdev="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-adev="Audio (2- 00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)" :dshow-aspect-ratio=16\:9 :dshow-chroma=BGR32 :dshow-vcodec=libx265 :dshow-fps=60 :dshow-acodec=mp4a :dshow-ab=96 :dshow-channels=2 :dshow-samplerate=44100 :no-dshow-config :no-dshow-tuner :live-caching=100 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=h.264,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:rtp{dst=227.0.0.1,port=8554,mux=ts}
```

With the above `dshow` commands I can get the picture to display perfectly in a local VLC session. With the RTP commands I seem to have successfully streamed the video card in a transport stream to a degree as I can get audio from the stream in a client VLC session.

The bit that seems to be going wrong though is the transcoding. I have printed the log below just for the server VLC session. h.264 does not seem to be a valid codec, nor is mp4v (which cannot be found on my machine).

Any suggestions on how to fix? I'm currently tearing my hair out on this...

```
-- logger module started --
main: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
dshow warning: ConnectFilters: No crossBar routes found (incompatible pin types)
stream_out_transcode error: cannot find video encoder (module:any fourcc:h.26). Take a look few lines earlier to see possible reason.
stream_out_transcode error: cannot create video chain
main warning: new sout input failed (sout_input: 04b265d0)
main error: cannot create packetizer output (I420)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 100 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (115683)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 103 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (115431)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (118376)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 106 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (126477)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114186)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (120540)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (107243)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (112596)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 107 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (124779)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (121605)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (123958)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (129063)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (96295)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 107 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (120359)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (116294)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (118648)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (124053)
main error: ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR  is called too late (pts_delay increased to 108 ms)
main error: buffer deadlock prevented
main warning: late buffer for mux input (138024)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (95972)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (102325)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114289)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (120643)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (128484)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (127838)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (107587)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (109940)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114095)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (109449)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (117841)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (128195)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (107249)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (109602)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (114131)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (123485)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (122832)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (129186)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (97323)
main warning: late buffer for mux input (99676)
main warning: no more input streams for this mux
-- logger module stopped --
```

Comment: Would you be opposed to using gstreamer instead of VLC? My experience in the past with VLC's streaming is that it can be extremely laggy, where Gstreamer tends to do much better.

Comment: Hi - basically all I need is a transport stream NextPVR can connect to. If you know a way in gstreamer, I am all ears. Thanks.

Comment: Alright. Working on it right now, but not too familiar with audio in Gstreamer. Will see what I can do, but may not be able to figure it out. If I haven't replied in a few days, give me a ping and I'll comment what I managed to figure out.